# How to make container responsive in flutter based on the content

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want a space between text and the above outlinedbutton. When I set space it shows different in different mobile devices. now the button is not shown full. how to show everything completely and make space between button and text. and that should be same in all devices.

button should be over the container not the text.
button should be like this at the bottom. it is above the container.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Instead of using positioned, you should be using row widget.

Comment: I have updated the question with image. please check it

Answer (score 2):

I will encourage using `padding` instead of `margin`.

There are some others changes have been made, described in code-comment

```dart
class RetreatWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            // if you need padding, wrap this Container with Padding widget
            Container(
              height: 110 + 48, // custom height 100 comes from ListItem height
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), //color of shadow
                      spreadRadius: 5, //spread radius
                      blurRadius: 7, // blur radius
                      offset: Offset(0, 2), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ]),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 110, // from [RetreatItem()]
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        RetreatItem(),
                        RetreatItem(),
                        RetreatItem(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          side: BorderSide(
                            width: 1.0,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          )),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Read More +',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RetreatItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const RetreatItem({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Image.network(
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/03/13/00/heart-7045303_960_720.jpg',
              // width: 200, // from parent
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, // for better view
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "garden - APRIL-2022",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have updated the question with additional image. button should be over the container. Image is given

Comment: Can you check update answer

Comment: The above code have a one simple problem. the button is inside the container. So I added a -6 value to bottom to Positioned widget then It works. but I don't know still it responsive for all screen devices.

Comment: You can test it on web by changing size.

Comment: okay. actually, I am not making for web only for mobile (different screensizes).  any way thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can give height and width using mediaquery. and add size box between button and container .
you can  replace this line to  constraints.maxHeight,

```
height Mediaquery.of(context).size.height*0.1
```

Comment: could you please show me in code. I didnt understand